# javascript encodeURIComponent function is acting weird

Tags: javascript

In my application I need to use javascript's function encodeURIComponent(url).

The interesting thing that I'm getting after using it is that when I do like this:

```
console.log(encodeURIComponent(this.currentUrl));
```

the result is: *http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fsch%2Fi.html%3F_from%3DR40%26_trksid%3Dp2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xnokia.TRS0%26_nkw%3Dnokia%26_sacat%3D0*

and when I use it like this:

```
console.log(this.baseUrl + "parse?url=" + encodeURIComponent(this.currentUrl));
```

the result is: *http://test.testapp.com/api/product/parse?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co…%3Dp2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xnokia.TRS0%26_nkw%3Dnokia%26_sacat%3D0*

```
this.currentUrl = "http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xnokia.TRS0&_nkw=nokia&_sacat=0"
this.baseUrl = "test.testapp.com/api/product/"
```

So as you can see  the first result is just encoded url that looks fine, but when I add it to other two strings somehow it changes it value... You can see that in second result after ebay.co there goes three dots which didn't appear in first result.. Can someone please explain why this could happen?

Comment: I think its just your browsers `console` implementation. Does anything happen when you click the **three dots**? I imagine it should expand out to show the full url

Comment: @AmmarCSE stupid me... you were right... false alarm.. :))